# A regular procedure assigned to TGetStrProc event receives an empty string parameter

Tags: delphi, event-handling, delphi-xe5

I tried to make an event handler out of a normal procedure, like I always did for `TNotifyEvent`, but this doesn't seem to work with `TGetStrProc`. The handler receives an empty string parameter.

```
program ProcAsTGetStrProc;

uses
  System.Classes, Winapi.Windows, System.SysUtils;

type
  TMyObject = class
  strict private
    _onLog: TGetStrProc;
    procedure _log(const msg: string);
  public
    procedure DoTheWork();
    property OnLog: TGetStrProc read _onLog write _onLog;
  end;

procedure mbox(msg: string);
begin
  MessageBox(0, PWideChar(msg), 'Test', 0);
end;

procedure TMyObject.DoTheWork();
begin
  _log('Doing the work');
end;

procedure TMyObject._log(const msg: string);
begin
  mbox(Format('TMyObject._log: "%s"', [msg]));
  if Assigned(_onLog) then _onLog(msg);
end;

procedure ProcLogging(const msg: string);
begin
  mbox(Format('ProcLogging: "%s"', [msg]));
end;

function MakeMethod(Data, Code: Pointer): TMethod;
begin
  Result.Data := Data;
  Result.Code := Code;
end;

var
  obj: TMyObject;

begin
  obj := TMyObject.Create();
  try
    obj.OnLog := TGetStrProc(MakeMethod(nil, @ProcLogging));
    obj.DoTheWork();
  finally
    obj.Free();
  end;
end.
```

**Expected output**

> TMyObject._log: "Doing the work"

> ProcLogging: "Doing the work"

**Actual output**

> TMyObject._log: "Doing the work"

> ProcLogging: ""

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of your standalone `ProcLogging()` procedure is wrong.

`TGetStrProc` is declared like this:

```pascal
TGetStrProc = procedure(const S: string) of object;
```

An `of object` reference expects a non-static class method to be assigned to it, which means there is an implicit `Self` parameter involved.  But there is no `Self` parameter in your `ProcLogging()` procedure.

Behind the scenes, `of object` is implemented using the `TMethod` record, where `TMethod.Code` is a pointer to the start of the method's implementation code, and the `TMethod.Data` is the value of the method's `Self` parameter.

The statement

```pascal
if Assigned(_onLog) then _onLog(msg);
```

Is roughly equivalent to:

```pascal
if _onLog.Code <> nil then _onLog.Code(_onLog.Data, msg);
```

So, when you use `TMethod` directly to call a standalone procedure, you have to declare the `Self` parameter explicitly to receive the `TMethod.Data` value and subsequent parameters correctly, eg:

```pascal
procedure ProcLogging(Self: Pointer; const msg: string);
begin
  mbox(Format('ProcLogging: "%s"', [msg]));
end;
```

Whatever you assign to the `TMethod.Data` field will be passed as-is to the `Self` parameter.  Specifying `nil` (as you are) is valid in this context, as long as the standalone procedure does not use it for anything.

Alternatively, you can use a non-instance `class` method instead of a standalone procedure.  A `class` method also has an implicit `Self` parameter (receiving a pointer to a class type rather than a pointer to an object instance), and thus is compatible with `of object`. However, a `class` method can be assigned as-is to an `of object` reference, so you don't have to mess around with `TMethod` directly, eg:

```pascal
type
  TLog = class
  public
    class procedure ProcLogging(const msg: string);
  end;

class procedure TLog.ProcLogging(const msg: string);
begin
  mbox(Format('ProcLogging: "%s"', [msg]));
end;

...
obj.OnLog := TLog.ProcLogging;
...
```

Comment: Indeed... My fault. Thank you very much.